# Share on LinkedIn using Restsharp

Tags: linkedin-api, restsharp

I'm having difficculty getting a share working on linkedin using restsharp. Here's my code:

```
    var shareMsg = new
    {
        comment = "Testing out the LinkedIn Share API with JSON",
        content = new
        {
            title = "Test post to LinkedIn",
            submitted_url = "http://www.somewebsite.com",
            submitted_image_url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/image.png"
        },
        visibility = new
        {
            code = "anyone"
        }
    };

    RestClient rc = new RestClient(LinkedInAppInfo.LinkedInBaseApiUrl);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(LinkedInAppInfo.SharePostPath, Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddParameter("format", "json");
    request.AddBody(shareMsg);
    request.AddParameter("oauth2_access_token", accessToken, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

    RestResponse restResponse = (RestResponse)rc.Execute(request);
    ResponseStatus responseStatus = restResponse.ResponseStatus;
```

The result i'm getting is:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Couldn't parse share document: error: Unexpected end of file after null",
  "requestId": "06ZU78FUNW",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1363551953855
}
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sofar, I found out 2 things ...If I use AddObject instead of AddBody, the json object is actually being send as part of the post.   Second .. as long as I use a AddParameter call, linkedin comes back with the error "Can not parse JSON share document." Removing the AddParameter calls solves that.  That brings me to the latest error: "Unknown authentication scheme" ... any thoughts on that?

Comment: I found the solution, see the question and answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601171/linkedin-restsharp-and-oauthbase-example